# How to codel model method from view with View variables?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to call an action method on ajax. It takes an int argument . 
For url of Ajax I am using 2 methods in model. 
CommonClass.CombineUrls(string1,string2) to combine 2 urls & CommonClass.GetRootPath() to get the application root path. 
Here is my code:

```
    function GetDetails(ContactId) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "@CommonClass.CombineUrls(CommonClass.GetRootPath(), "Controller1/Method1/" + ContactId)",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Name: " + data.FirstName);
            }
        });
    }
```

"ContactId" is not available to url. As, it's considering everything as server side code. So is there any way of combining server side & client side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use JavaScript variables inside Razor like that, what you'd have to do instead is something like this, using `Url.Action`:

```
url: "@Url.Action("Method1", "Controller1")" + "?ContactId=" + ContactId
```

Or alternatively (**and better**):

```
url: "@Url.Action("Method1", "Controller1")",
data: { ContactId: ContactId }
```

If `Url.Action` isn't possible/applicable in your scenario, then use your existing functions, but still use the `data` property:

```
url: "@CommonClass.CombineUrls(CommonClass.GetRootPath(), "Controller1/Method1/")",
data: { ContactId: ContactId }
```

Comment: I am using the 3rd option you provided. But, I wish a way to use combination of JS variable & server side code. So that I can avoid data of ajax call. :)

Comment: @RasmitaDash You can't combine the two in a single method call, you'd have to have a separate AJAX call that passed the variable, then returned the result of your function, then use that result in your second AJAX call. I would recommend using `data` though and just the one call.